# Nested Form - I cannot get all of the attributes params to pass through to my strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-many-through, strong-parameters

Working on a project with a has_many_through join table with an additional attribute on the join table. My models are wines, foods, and the join table is pairings. I am not getting all of the attributes params to pass through to my strong params. I have tried approaching this several different ways - through the foods controller and the pairings controller, but through the wines controller seems to be the most direct path. On the wines new form, I ask for basic information about the wine, allow the user to select foods to pair with from all of the foods previously entered, and allow them to enter a new food and indicate what type of pairing it is (which is the additional attribute on the join table). From the form, I am getting the food_ids from the pre-existing foods and I'm getting the pairings attributes for the type of pairing, but I am not getting the food attributes.

**Models:**

```
class Wine < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :wine_tasting_notes
    has_many :tasting_notes, :through => :wine_tasting_notes
    has_many :pairings, inverse_of: :wine
    has_many :foods, :through => :pairings
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pairings, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :foods

        def pairings_attributes=(attributes)
            attributes.values.each do |att|
                if !att[:food_id].blank? || !att[:food_attributes].blank?
                    pairing = Pairing.new(att)
                    pairing.wine = self
                    self.pairings << pairing
                end
            end
        end
              
   
end
class Food < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :pairings, inverse_of: :food
    has_many :wines, :through => :pairings
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pairings, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :wines

end

class Pairing < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :wine
    belongs_to :food

    def food_attributes=(attributes)
        food = Food.find_or_create_by(attributes)
        self.food_id = food.id
        binding.pry
    end
 
end
```

**Wines_Controller**

```
class WinesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        # binding.pry
        @wines = Wine.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
        
    end

    def new
        # binding.pry
        @wine = Wine.new
        @wine.user_id = current_user.id
        @pairings = @wine.pairings.build
        @food = @pairings.build_food
        
        binding.pry
        
    end

    def show
        # binding.pry
        @wine = Wine.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        binding.pry
        @wine = Wine.new(wine_params)
               
        binding.pry
        # @wine.user_id = current_user.id
        if @wine.save
            # binding.pry
            redirect_to @wine, notice: "Successfully created Wine"
        else
            # binding.pry
            render :new
        end
    end

    private

    def wine_params
        params.require(:wine).permit(:id, :wine_name, :color, :grape, :avg_price, :acidity, :sweetness, :user_id, pairings_attributes: [:id, :pairing_type], food_ids:[],\
        food_attributes: [:id, :food_name, :food_acidity, :food_sweetness])
    end

end
```

**New wine Form**

```
<h1>Add a Wine</h1>
<br>
<%= form_for @wine do |f| %>
    <div class ="settings">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
    <%= f.label :wine_name %><%= f.text_field :wine_name %>
    
    <%= f.label :color %><%= f.text_field :color %>
    
    <%= f.label :grape %><%= f.text_field :grape %>
        
    <%= f.label :avg_price %><%= f.text_field :avg_price %>
    
    <%= f.label :acidity %><%= f.text_field :acidity %>
    
    <%= f.label :sweetness %><%= f.text_field :sweetness %>
    </div>
    <br>
    Food Pairings:
    <br>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "wine[food_ids][]", nil %>
    <% Food.all.each do |food| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "wine[food_ids][]", food.id, @wine.food_ids.include?(food.id), id: dom_id(food) %>
        <%= label_tag dom_id(food), food.food_name %><br>
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <strong><em>To Add a New Food Pairing:</em></strong>
    <br>
    <%= f.fields_for :food do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :id %>
        <%= ff.label :"Food Name:" %>
        <%= ff.text_field :food_name %>
        <%= ff.label :"Food Acidity:" %>
        <%= ff.text_field :food_acidity %>
        <%= ff.label :"Food Sweetness:" %>
        <%= ff.text_field :food_sweetness %>
        
        <br>
        <br>
    <% end %>
    <strong>Type of Pairing: </strong>
    
    <%= f.fields_for :pairings do |fff| %>
    <%= fff.label :pairing_type, "Congruent", "value" => "Congruent" %><%= fff.radio_button :pairing_type, "Congruent", checked: true %>
    <%= fff.label :pairing_type, "Contrasting", "value" => "Contrasting" %><%= fff.radio_button :pairing_type, "Contrasting", checked: false %>
    <% end %>      
    <br>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**General params when I submit the form**

```
[2] pry(#<WinesController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"MQy7Or4AjBLi11uEFEgBVAZnCT9kgaltqMPxIZ4X2d2BnMZwshQZkUKKCAzeQzE77pycsZN7SVOiX6NsPH/Dng==", "wine"=><ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>"1", "wine_name"=>"Molly Dooker The Boxer", "color"=>"Red", "grape"=>"Shiraz", "avg_price"=>"29", "acidity"=>"3.6", "sweetness"=>"4", "food_ids"=>["", "1", "2"], "food"=>{"id"=>"", "food_name"=>"Duck", "food_acidity"=>"8", "food_sweetness"=>"3"}, "pairings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"pairing_type"=>"Congruent"}}} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Create Wine", "controller"=>"wines", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

**Strong params - wine_params**

```
[1] pry(#<WinesController>)> wine_params
Unpermitted parameter: :food
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"wine_name"=>"Molly Dooker The Boxer", "color"=>"Red", "grape"=>"Shiraz", "avg_price"=>"29", "acidity"=>"3.6", "sweetness"=>"4", "user_id"=>"1", "pairings_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"pairing_type"=>"Congruent"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>, "food_ids"=>["", "1", "2"]} permitted: true>
```

Appreciate any insights-

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use accepts_nested_attributes for `:food` in `wine` model because you have has_many through: relationship between food and wine which is indirect.

you should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :foods` in pairing model with singular symbol i.e. :food

Have a [look](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through)